# Strange async behavior in Node with Mongoose and promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise

So I'm using Node.js + Mongoose + Lie as a promise library. The code is as follows:

```
var User = require('../models/user'),
    Promise = require('lie'),
    jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
    config = require('../../config');

module.exports = function(express) {
    var router = express.Router();

    router.post('/', function(req, res) {
        if (!req.body.username) return res.json({ success: false, reason: 'Username not supplied.' });
        if (!req.body.password) return res.json({ success: false, reason: 'Password not supplied.' });

        var findUser = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) reject (err);
                if (!user) reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
                if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password)) reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
                resolve(user);
            });
        });

        var sendToken = function(user) {
            var token = jwt.sign({ username: user.username }, config.secret, { expiresIn: 2 * 60 * 60 });
            res.json({ success: true, token: token });
        };

        findUser.then(function(value) {
            sendToken(value);
        }).catch(function(reason) {
            res.send(reason);
        });

    return router;
};
```

So basically it's an auth route, which sends a signed `jwt` if everything is good. The *strange* behavior is that if I send a wrong username, the server throws an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'validPassword' of null
```

So, it says that the `user === null` when it reaches the password validity check, HOWEVER, before this validity check, there is a check that a user is found, mainly

```
if (!user) reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
```

And here the server already knows that `user === null`, hence it should reject this promise with `success: false`, and this piece of code should be thrown into `catch` part, but it doesn't happen.

Any ideas, please?

I should add that if I change that `if (!user.validPassword...` part to `else if` instead of `if`, it works like it should. However I cannot understand why any code is still executed after the promise gets rejected.

### EDIT

While learning node, I mainly used the [MEAN Machine book](https://leanpub.com/mean-machine), which is a great help, and there they use this syntax:

```
if (!user) {
    //
} else if (user) {
    //
}
```

But I guess it should work my way as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not stopping execution of your function on `reject`, so if `findOne` results in empty result `validPassword` is still get called.

Probably you need to add `return`:

```
 User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
   if (err)
     return reject (err);
   if (!user)
     return reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
   if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password))
     return reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
   resolve(user);
 });
```

Or use `else if`:

```
 User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
   if (err) { 
     reject (err);
   } else if (!user) {
     reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
   } else if (!user.validPassword(req.body.password))
     reject({ success: false, reason: 'User not found or password is incorrect.' });
   } else {
     resolve(user);
   }
 });
```

Comment: That makes sense.. I think I just thought that it is implied that `resolve` or `reject` should stop the execution :D Thanks!